# Jitter Issue on a Camera in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, jitter

I get an issue with my camera when I move my player around in a level.
What I mean by this is:
When looking around using the mouse, the game runs smoothly, however once I start to use WASD to move my player around, the camera jitters.

[Here is a video of just that (might be hard to percieve)](https://youtu.be/39NQzRUB8jo)

My camera script and the the script that makes the camera follow the player are two different scripts and the issue only occurs when the camera has to follow the player, I thus assumed that the issue was from the MovePlayerCam script which goes as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayerCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform CamHolder;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = CamHolder.position;
        // camHolder is an empty GameObject that is contained by a player Parent Object that has the player movement script
    }
}
```

I have another project of mine, with the same MovePlayerCam script, in which the issue doesn't occur. However, in this project I am using the old unity input system to move my player around. In the project I'm having the issue with, I am trying to learn how to use the new Input system, I might've broken something there so here is my player movement script as well:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine;

public class BaseMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("ref")]
    Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform orientation;
    public PlayerInputs playerControls;

    [Header("Values")]
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpStrength;
    public float maxMoveSpeed;
    public float airMultiplier;
    public float groundDrag;
    public float airDrag;
    public float crouchDrag;
    public float slideDrag;
    bool grounded;


    Vector3 moveDirection;
    private InputAction move;
    private InputAction vertical;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerControls = new PlayerInputs();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        move = playerControls.Player.Move;
        move.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        move.Disable();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.drag = groundDrag;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        MoveInputs();
    }

    private void MoveInputs()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.magnitude < maxMoveSpeed)
        {
            moveDirection = orientation.forward * move.ReadValue<Vector2>().y + orientation.right * move.ReadValue<Vector2>().x;
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * airMultiplier, ForceMode.Force);
        }
    }
}
```

To Fix this, I tried putting the MovePlayerCam script in lateUpdate, in a FixedUpdate and none worked. I still get the camera jitter when moving around. So please help lmao

Comment: You are doing physics work inside of Update.  Try calling `MoveInputs` in `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: It didn't fix anything, Exept that I had to readjust some variables to make the player move at a decent speed, the camera still jitters :/

Comment: Did you try changing the camera movement to `FixedUpdate` as well?

Comment: as mentioned in the post, changing the update didn't work

Comment: You are moving the camera by adding a force every frame, this not a framerate indepenant way of doing it. You have two choices, manually specify the velocity in some stable way (only modifying it non-framerate-dependantly). This will lose pure physics simulation. or ease your camera movement by lerping it towards the position each frame

Comment: @rshepp op is correct, late update or regular update will make no difference to this problem, it has nothing to do with execution order

Comment: @reshep I don't mean to be pedantic but this rule of thumb is a poor one. You should move your camera in relation to the place where you move your camera's target - this will minimise jitter. Say for you are tweening based on movement in fixed update, using late update will either miss movement, or apply tweening function more than once. I don't say this without authority. [Cinemachine provides both options exactly for this reason](https://github.com/svermeulen/CebuGameJam/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/Template/Add-Ons/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineBrain.cs)